# Передача значения в функцию Flask

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть файл base.py со множеством списков(больше 50) вида

```
model1 = [
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://'
]

model2 = [
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://',
    'https://'
]
```

Также в другом файле func.py написаны функции для обработки url из файла base.py

Мне нужно в HTML шаблон вывести ссылки из файла base и результаты функций из файла func

Используя Flask, вывожу ссылки следующим образом

```
import base

def index():
    return render_template("index.html",
        url = base)
```

Вопрос: Как передать нужный url определенной модели из конкретного списка из файла base в функцию файла func и вывести результат этой функции в HTML шаблоне используя Flask?

Сам шаблон

```
<tr>
<td>Model 1</td>
<td><a href="{{ url.model1[0] }}" target="_blank">{{ результат func }}</a></td>
<td><a href="{{ url.model1[1] }}" target="_blank">{{ результат func }}</a></td>
<td><a href="{{ url.model1[2] }}" target="_blank">{{ результат func }}</a></td>
<td><a href="{{ url.model1[3] }}" target="_blank">{{ результат func }}</a></td>
<td><a href="{{ url.model1[4] }}" target="_blank">{{ результат func }}</a></td>
<td><a href="{{ url.model1[5] }}" target="_blank">{{ результат func }}</a></td>
<td><a href="{{ url.model1[6] }}" target="_blank">{{ результат func }}</a></td>
</tr>
```

В файле func.py лежит 6 функций, для каждой функции в списке из файла base.py

func.py

```
def url1 (murl):
#####################
    print(price)

def url2 (murl):
#####################
    print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял, то вам нужны не списки урлов, а словари, которые будут связывать урл и метод. Вызовы методов стоит выполнить до рендеринга шаблона, передав в него результаты выполнения методов.

```
from itertools import chain

import base
import func

model1 = {
    'url': func.foo1,
    'url': func.foo2,
}

model2 = {
    'url': func.foo3,
    'url': func.foo4,
}


def index():
    context = {url: fun() for url, fun in chain(model1.items(), model2.items())}
    return render_template("index.html", context=context)
```

Теперь можно проитерироваться по context в шаблоне чтобы вывести результаты.

```
<tr>
{% for model_url, func_result in context.items() %}
<td><a href="{{ model_url }}" target="_blank">{{ func_result }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```